# Where to specify Ansible role's dependencies

Tags: ansible

It seems that Ansible Galaxy will understand it has to download dependencies if those are specified in either meta/main.yml or a requirements.yml file.

Is there a best practice for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TL;DR:

- `meta/main.yml` is for roles-to-role dependency
- `requirements.yml` is for playbook-to-role dependency.

---

Playbook can contain dependencies in `meta/main.yml`. Dependent roles will be installed during `ansible-galaxy install`, so if role A depends on role B, role B will be installed together with role A. Role B will be also applied before role A is applied automatically during `ansible-playbook` run.

Roles mentioned in `requirements.yml` are requirements of your local playbook. You can install roles from Galaxy with `ansible-galaxy -r requirements.yml` but the `requirements.yml` file is used only for your convenience of installing roles needed to run the playbook. No automatic/automagic execution of roles mentioned there should happen.